# reading multiple csv file from a different directory in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, opencsv

```
import csv
import pandas

df_list = []
path = "C:/Users/bubai/Desktop/try/scrapy/output"
#all csv file
for file in os.listdir(path):
    #print(file)
    df_list.append(file)  # all csv file in this
#print(df_list) 
for i in df_list:
    df = pandas.read_csv(i)  # open one by one 
    print(df)
```

I have some error:-FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'poem1.csv' does not exist: b'poem1.csv'
file name are saved like poem1.csv
poem10.csv
poem11.csv
poem12.csv
poem13.csv
poem14.csv
poem15.csv
poem16.csv
poem17.csv
poem18.csv
poem19.csv
poem2.csv
poem20.csv

Comment: try this  ,     df_list.append(path  + '/' + file)

Comment: thank  you man.... its works

Comment: This solution may be what you are looking for: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/12762476>

Comment: can you explain this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the filename to the path.

```
import csv
import pandas
import os

df_list = []
path = "C:/Users/bubai/Desktop/try/scrapy/output"
#all csv file
for file in os.listdir(path):
    df_list.append(os.path.join(path,file))  # all csv file in this
#print(df_list) 
for i in df_list:
    df = pandas.read_csv(i)  # open one by one 
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the directory name with the filename in order to refer to the file.

```
import os

df = pandas.read_csv(os.path.join(path, i)
```